# Update Venn using jvenn, after deleting sets in random order

Tags: javascript, venn-diagram

We're working on developing a database wherein we are using Jvenn.

"http://jvenn.toulouse.inra.fr/app/example.html"

However, we're facing an issue regarding random deletion of sets. The text area gets emptied when any random set is deleted, but the venn diagram does not. When we tried to do the same in reverse order, the venn diagram changes along with the set.

For ex., when there are 6 sets and the fourth is deleted, the number of terms in the fourth set get emptied in set 4 from the text area as well as from the venn diagram. But there still are 6 sets being shown in the diagram. But, when we go in the reverse order deleting entry 6th>5th>4th>3th the venn diagram also changes.

Can anyone help us with understanding how we could implement such a change in our code, so as to add a random deletion option.

Comment: It's hard to say much without a [mcve]. Can you add your code showing the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can check the working of the venn using the "Load example" button on the link posted in the question. I don't know how deleting sets and updating the venn after doing so works. Jvenn is an open source tool. The source code can be accessed using the following link [link](https://forgemia.inra.fr/genotoul-bioinfo/jvenn/tree/master/docs). Thanks. @ggorlen